# C++ idiom for dynamically populating objects and destroying at return

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using C++0x.

I have a function `call_third_party`, that receives a list of `A*`, converts it to a list of `B*`, then passes that list of `B*` into function `third_party`. After `third_party` is called, the list of `B*` is no longer needed.

As the name suggests, I have no control over `third_party`.

Currently I have something like this.

```
void call_third_party(const vector<A*>& as) {
    vector<unique_ptr<B>> allocated_bs;
    vector<B*> bs;
    vector<A*>::iterator it;
    for (it = as.begin(); it < as.end(); it++) {
        unique_ptr<B> b(new B(*it));
        allocated_bs.push_back(b);
        bs.push_back(b.get());
    }
    third_party(bs);
}
```

Just in case this helps. Here are `B`'s constructor and `third_party`'s signature.

```
void third_party(const vector<B*>& bs);
B(A* a);
```

Is there a better, idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: +1 for `allocated_bs`: otherwise known as Norton antivirus components

Comment: To clarify, your functions take lists (vectors) of `A*` and `B*`, respectively, **not** `A` and `B`?! Could you make this clearer? It might need to be `new B(**it)` I think. Can you publish the signature of `third_party()` and of `B::B()` please?

Comment: Kerrek, I edited the question to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
void call_third_party(const vector<A*>& as)
{
   std::vector<B> b(as.begin(), as.end());
   std::vector<B*> bp(b.size());
   std::transform(b.begin(), b.end(), bp.begin(), [](B& b) { return &b; });
   third_party(bp);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Would

```
// change name to held_b or something?
vector<B> allocated_bs;
// ...
for(...) {
    auto emplaced = allocated_bs.emplace(allocated_bs.end(), *it);
    bs.push_back(&*emplaced);
```

be possible? I don't see the need for dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Boost's [`ptr_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html) might make that a lot simpler.

Comment: Based on my reading of the question, `third_party` can't be changed to accept a `ptr_vector` - otherwise this would be a great suggestion.

Comment: That would require modifying `third_party`, wouldn't it? Or do you mean instead of `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>>`?

Comment: @Mark, @Luc: Because nothing in the question actually mentioned the other library wanting a vector, I'm guessing `third_party` actually needs a `B**`, i.e. `third_party(&bs[0], bs.size());`, in which case `ptr_vector<B> v; third_party(v.c_array(), v.size());` should work.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, seems a bit much to allocate a second vector just for the pointers - shock horror, why not do it the old fashioned way?

```
template <typename PtrContainer>
struct auto_delete
{
  ~auto_delete()
  {
    for(auto it = _cont.begin(); it != _cont.end(); ++it)
      delete *it;
  }
  PtrContainer& _cont;
};

void call_third_party(const vector<A*>& as)
{
  std::vector<B*> allocated_bs;
  allocated_bs.reserve(as.size());
  // this will take care of cleanup - irrespective of where the exit point is
  auto_delete<std::vector<B*>> dt = { allocated_bs }; 
  (void)dt;
  for(auto it = as.begin(); it != as.end(); ++it)
    allocated_bs.push_back(new B(*it));
  third_party(allocated_bs);
}
```

Comment: "*why not do it the old fashioned way?*" It's more code and more error-prone for no benefit. Indeed, there's a reason it's the old fashioned way.